# How to Assign Multidimensional Array Values to Tableview Cell swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift3, tableview, cell

```
    var QuestionID = [String]()
    var Questions = [String]()
    var AnswersID = [[String]]()
    var AnswersArray = [[String]]()
    var AnswerType = [String]()


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
    IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

       let cell = 
             tblQuickQuestions.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
             "idQuickQuestionsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! 
             QuickQuestionsTableViewCell
       cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
       cell.selectionStyle = .none
       cell.lblRadio!.text = AnswersArray[indexPath.sections]
       [indexPath.rows]

      return cell
    }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
     section: Int) -> Int{
         return AnswersArray[section].count
 }
```

/*********************************************************************************************/
**My Array Values:**

Questions ID:              ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

Question:                     ["How is the flooring?", "Test Question ???", "what is ur bdate", "Test Question", "How are you ...?"]

Answer Type:              ["Checkbox", "Checkbox", "Drop Down Menu", "Drop Down Menu", "Radio Buttons"]

Answers ID:                  [["3"], ["5"], ["6", "7", "8"], ["9"], ["10", "11", "12"]]

AnswersArray:            [["test"], ["ans"], ["2 April", "7 jan", "15aug"], ["lklklk"], ["aa", "bb", "cc"]]

I want to implement an Question, Answers Quiz in which Answers are of multiple choice and can be of type Radio Buttons, Checkboxes or Lists. I have implemented Two dimensional array for answers like: Answers[["1","2","3"],["1"],["1","2","3","4","5"]]. where First inner array represents answers for first question, second inner array for second question and so on. and for Questions like: Questions["Question1","Question2","Question3"]. Now I want to assign these values to label present in table view cell and wants to display next Question and answers on next button click.

Comment: It would be better if you could also share your code to show what you have tried, or to know where you went wrong.

Comment: Refine your question for exact need @Bipin Tamkhane

Comment: I just wants to display single question at a time with Multiple choice Answers present for that question and on next click wants to display next question answers

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by creating `Singleton` array of `Dictionary`.

Suppose my singleton array name is 'MainArray'.
So i have created one function which will be called from `viewDidLoad()` function.

```
func gatherData(){

    MainArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

    let QuestionsID : [String] = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
    let Question : [String] = ["How is the flooring?", "Test Question ???", "what is ur bdate", "Test Question", "How are you ...?"]
    let AnswerType : [String] = ["Checkbox", "Checkbox", "Drop Down Menu", "Drop Down Menu", "Radio Buttons"]
   // let AnswersID : [[String]] = [["3"], ["5"], ["6", "7", "8"], ["9"], ["10", "11", "12"]]
    let AnswersArray : [[String]] =  [["test"], ["ans"], ["2 April", "7 jan", "15aug"], ["lklklk"], ["aa", "bb", "cc"]]

    var emptyDictionary = [String: Any]()

    for ind in 0...QuestionsID.count-1{
        emptyDictionary["QID"] = QuestionsID[ind]
        emptyDictionary["QNAME"] = Question[ind]
        emptyDictionary["ANSWERTYPE"] = AnswerType[ind]

        var innerArray : [String] = []
        for inner in 0...AnswersArray.count-1{
              innerArray = [AnswersArray[ind][inner]]
            break
        }
       emptyDictionary["ANSWERARRAY"] = innerArray
        emptyDictionary["ANSWER_USER"] = ""
        MainArray.append(emptyDictionary)

    }
    print("MainArray:\(MainArray)")

}
```

**Output from console:**

```
 MainArray:[["ANSWERARRAY": ["test"], "ANSWER_USER": "", "ANSWERTYPE": "Checkbox", "QNAME": "How is the flooring?", "QID": "2"], ["ANSWERARRAY": ["ans"], "ANSWER_USER": "", "ANSWERTYPE": "Checkbox", "QNAME": "Test Question ???", "QID": "3"], ["ANSWERARRAY": ["2 April"], "ANSWER_USER": "", "ANSWERTYPE": "Drop Down Menu", "QNAME": "what is ur bdate", "QID": "4"], ["ANSWERARRAY": ["lklklk"], "ANSWER_USER": "", "ANSWERTYPE": "Drop Down Menu", "QNAME": "Test Question", "QID": "5"], ["ANSWERARRAY": ["aa"], "ANSWER_USER": "", "ANSWERTYPE": "Radio Buttons", "QNAME": "How are you ...?", "QID": "6"]]
```

By using `MainArray` index position you can switch between array values which is nothing but single dictionary for that index, and you can display results as per the data in dictionary.

If this solves your problem, don't forget to accept the answer.